# Within a loop how can I change directories that have a specific name?

Tags: r, subdirectory

I assign the name of the species in a vector

```
sp1 <- Basper
```

to directly access the files for example:

```
occ_sp1 <- read.table (paste ("H: / Botrops_p /", sp1, '. txt', sep = ""), 
                       header = TRUE, sep = "\ t")
```

```html
all.species <-list.files("H:/Sim_crotalus/Crota.puntos.pam",pattern=".txt")
sp.names <- gsub(".txt","",all.species)
sp.combn <- combn(sp.names,2)
sp.combn 

resul <- matrix(nrow=406,ncol=7,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(resul) <- c("D1","D2","p.D1","p.D2")

  for(i in 1:ncol(sp.combn)){
  print(i)
  sp1 <- sp.combn[1,i]
  sp2 <- sp.combn[2,i]
  
  occ_sp1 <- read.table(paste("H:/E_Crotalus/par1/",sp1,'.txt',sep = ""), header=TRUE,sep="\t")
occ_sp2 <- read.table(paste("H:/E_Crotalus/par1/",sp2,'.txt',sep = ""), header=TRUE,sep="\t")

clim2 <- stack(list.files(path="H:/Crotalus_pam/M2/Caqui", pattern='.asc',full.names = TRUE))
```

w I need to access folders(subdirectories) that have the same name of *sp1* to stack the raster files that I have tried

```
setwd ("H: / Botrops_p / Basper")

clim2 <- stack (list.files (pattern = '. asc', full.names = TRUE))
```

there is some way to avoid putting the name of the folder in `setwd()` and relating it to the assigned *sp1* in the beginning

## Trying to be a little clearer about the problem I put a broader example of my code

I have a list of species and I will make combinations of pairs of species in the case of txt files, no problem because I assign the name of the file to the vector sp1 <- Catrox

But in the case of the .asc they are different folders that have the same name of sp1 for example in this case Catrox and they contain 6 raster each one

In this case I would have to manually change the name Caqui

There is some way to recognize the folder as the file with the same name

Comment: `list.files` has a *path* argument. Why not dynamically pass it into there?

Comment: Thanks! @Parfait because I have to specify the name of the folder, will I be able to relate it to the name of sp1?

Comment: I'm not quite understanding. Please post the fuller code block and even the longer form of your code block that you need dynamically changed. `list.files` also has `recursive` to traverse subfolders.

Comment: 1) Your path names (and `sep = "\ t"`) have too many spaces, please correct that. 2) If all .txt files in the folder are to be read in, you probably don't need to pass the filename.

Comment: I see you posted a fuller code block which appears to handle your needs, namely passing the *sp1* name into path with `paste`. Please explain what does not work with the current code? Error? Undesired result?

Comment: the code works currently if I do not put it with the loop. When I put it in the loop what doesnt work is to change the path of the folder to make the stack with the rasters because they are different for each sp. I have 29 folders with 6 raster each one @Pairfait

Comment: thank you for your interest in helping me @Rui Barradas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! My interests in snakes and R have crossed over!

Without seeing the structure of your directories and files on disk, it's difficult to figure out exactly what you need to do, but something along these lines might help:

```
# If sp1 is 'Caqui', this will return the paths of all .asc files
#   in the 'H:/Crotalus_pam/M2/Caqui/' directory:
thisDir <- paste("H:/Crotalus_pam/M2/", sp1, sep="")
clim2 <- stack(list.files(path=thisDir, pattern='.asc', full.names=TRUE))
```

If you're still having issues, please update your question with more details (especially details of how your files and directories are organised).

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest in snakes!! and for your help to my problem that worked perfectly!! @Stewart Macdonald